# How to specify a GPT name containing spaces with parted?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, parted

I'd like to create a single big partition on a GPT hard drive taking the whole space using *parted* version 3.2 (so the old version since Debian didn't updated it already)

According to the man page of version 3.2 the command is :

`mkpart part-type [fs-type] start end`

But it doesn't explain for a GPT disk at all. However the [user's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#mkpart) for version 3.3 explains it better :

`mkpart [part-type name fs-type] start end`

> *part-type* […] may be specified only with ‘msdos’ or ‘dvh’ partition tables.
>   A *name* must be specified for a ‘gpt’ partition table.
>   *fs-type* is required for data partitions

---

So I'm making this command (that works) :

`sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart name 0% 100%`

(I don't know why it says *fs-type* is required since it works without specifying it). Anyway this command works but I have several problems :

**1) I can't have a name with spaces (even in interactive mode).** This doesn't work :

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart 'Name of the partition' 0% 100%
parted: invalid token: of
File system type?  [ext2]?
```

**2) It leaves a MB out of the partition unallocated.** This is the result of `parted -l /dev/sdb` command :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 16777216s
Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  16775167s  16773120s               namePart

Disk /dev/sdb: 8590MB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  8589MB  8588MB               namePart
```

Whereas when partitioning with *gdisk* :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 16777216s
Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  16777182s  16775135s               namePart

Disk /dev/sdb: 8590MB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  8590MB  8589MB               namePart
```

**3) It asks for a file system on interactive mode and I have to specify one**

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart
Partition name?  []? name                                                 
File system type?  [ext2]?
```

Comment: Have you tried with double quotation marks instead? i.e. "these" ?

Comment: Yes obviously, I tried with " with ' with nothing at all and even with \ before the space.

Answer (score 2):

Your bash is eating your double quotes. Parted need to see them. You can enclose the name *and* double quotes in single quotes:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart '"Name of the partition"' 0% 100%
```